# Преобразование string в String^

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Не могу найти метод преобразования string в String^... Не подскажете?

Comment: Анна, указывайте, пожалуйста, метку `c++-cli`, с правильной меткой больше шансов получить ответ. Дело в том, что C++ CLI это не C++ несмотря на некоторое сходство, а отсутствующая метка создает впечатление, что речь именно о C++.

Comment: string - может иметь "разночтения", имеется ввиду std:string? Посмотреть конструкторы `System::String`

Answer (score 1):

Прямого преобразования - нету.

Смотрим конструкторы http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor и класс http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Наиболее подходят два - `System::String^::String(char*)` и `System::String^::String(wchar_t*)`.
Класс `std::string` имеет наиболее подходящий  метод `c_str()`.

Итог

```
std::string data;   
System::String^ s = gcnew System::String(data.c_str());
```

Ansi - строки могут терять "кодировку", лучше использовать юникод.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! К сожалению мне не удалось им воспользоваться...

           string namea = AddName();

           String^ nameb = gcnew String(namea->c_str());

Этот вариант заканчивается ошибкой:
error C2819: type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
Остальные так же не удачны... Не знаете как решить проблему?

Comment: вы не дали никакого примера кода. Попробуйте заменить `->` на точку `namea.c_str()`